# Calling results of applying f to expr inside NestList

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, recursion

Being new to *Mathematica*, I try to follow the suggestions of using `NestList`, `Map`, `Table` instead of `For/While` loops. Things have gone well so far, until I face this problem. I now want my function `f` to calculate the next result, assume that it is `f[f[f[x]]]`, using the two last results, namely `f[f[x]]` and `f[x]`. Can I achieve that goal without using For/While/Do loops?

To make the question more specific and easier to answer, this is my code:

```
LocalPotential[{v0_, va_, vab_}] := Module[
   {potential = v0, grad = va, hess= vab, deltavab, next},
   potential += deltaphi.grad + (1./2.)*(deltaphi.hess.deltaphi);
   grad += hess.deltaphi;
   hess = MyHessian[hess, grad];
   next = {potential, grad, hess};
   next
]

totallist =  Table[
   NestList[LocalPotential, {Potential0[n, 100.], Gradient0[n], DBH[n]}, nstep], 
   {i, 1, realisation}
 ];
```

I now want my function `MyHessian` to calculate the next result using not just the previous one but also the one before that, i.e. `va[n-1]` and `va[n-2]`. What should I do? Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a hint.

Consider you want to implement a function $f(n)=2^n$  using `NetList`. You will do something like this:

```
NestList[#*2&,1,5]
```

So we used the fact that $f(n+1)=2f(n)$.

Now we will implement Fibonacci sequence where $g(n)=g(n-1)+g(n-2)$

```
NestList[{#[[2]],#[[1]]+#[[2]]}&,{0,1},10]
(*{{0,1},{1,1},{1,2},{2,3},{3,5},{5,8},{8,13},{13,21},{21,34},{34,55},{55,89}} *)
```

What happens here? The function $g$ acts on a pair $g: (x,y)\rightarrow (y,x+y)$.
So effectively it saves $y$, i.e. $g(n-1)$, for you to be used during next iteration, where it becomes $g(n-2)$.

In the end we don't need pairs, we need just list of second arguments. So our function becomes:

```
Last@Transpose@NestList[{#[[2]],#[[1]]+#[[2]]}&,{0,1},10]
(*{1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89 *)
```

If you are not yet very comfortable with pure functions (`#@/&` stuff), you can rewrite it as:

```
g[{x_,y_}]:={y,x+y};
Last@Transpose@NestList[g,{0,1},10]
```